# How do I close a secondary Activity gracefully?

Tags: android

I managed to create a secondary Activity, but now I wonder how I can close it again.

```
public void button_onClick(View v){
   finish();
}
```

works when I'm dealing with just one Activity at a time, but how do I let the secondary Activity close the entire application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "close the entire application" in Android, any more than you "close the entire application" in a Web app. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238) for more on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me.
In the **FIRST** Activity:

```
private boolean flag = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(!flag)
        flag = true;
    else
        finish();
    super.onResume();
}
```